# How to use WinAPI to cover another window

Tags: c#, winapi, window

I have 2 windows, or rather window handles. I want to get the position and size of one window, and apply them to the other window, so that the second window covers the first completely. 
Right now I'm using `GetWindowRect()` to get the position and size of one window, for example,

```
IntPtr hWnd1 = some window handle;
Rect rect = new Rect();
GetWindowRect(hWnd1, ref rect);
```

and after some googling, it seems I have to use `SetWindowPos()` to move and resize my other window on top.

```
SetWindowPos(hWnd2, some coords here);
```

However, I don't know how to convert the `RECT` struct returned by `GetWindowRect()` into coordinates I can use with `SetWindowPos()`, any help appreciated.

Comment: Try using `MoveWindow()` on `hWnd2`. It ought to work.

Comment: `MoveWindow()` has the same problems, the coordinates are off and it looks like http://images.punyman.com/uploads/c4e4a299ce6b9f0770b2.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to convert "Left, Top, Right, Bottom" to "X, Y, Width, Height":

```
RECT rct = GetWindowRect(windowHandler);
SetWindowPos(windowHandler, HWND_TOP, rct.Left, rct.Top, rct.Right - rct.Left, rct.Bottom - rct.Top, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

## Update

You probably should use *GetWindowPlacement* instead of *GetWindowRect*, like this:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT place;
bool ok = GetWindowPlacement(hwndTarget, out place);
ok = SetWindowPos(hwndSrc, new IntPtr(0), place.NormalPosition.Left, place.NormalPosition.Top, place.NormalPosition.Width, place.NormalPosition.Height, SetWindowPosFlags.ShowWindow);
```

Note this will only work if the window is in a "restored" position (not maximized).

I'm omitting the interop imports and structures, you can find it in http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowPlacement.html and http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowPos.html

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to be working. It moves the window, but the coordinates are all wrong and don't match at all.

Comment: @ron975 You're right, since *GetWindowRect()* returns *screen coordinates* and *SetWindowPos()* expects *client coordinates*, please check the updated answer

Comment: You can also use [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx) to set the window's position. See the comment at the top about whether the parameters are interpreted as screen or client coordinates.

Comment: You don't need the `+1` when converting to width and height, since in Windows **"By convention, the right and bottom edges of the rectangle are normally considered exclusive. In other words, the pixel whose coordinates are ( right, bottom ) lies immediately outside of the rectangle"**